# Android apt updating from 1.4 to 1.7 version

Tags: java, android, gradle, annotations, android-apt

Hi I wanted to upgrade **android-apt** in my project from version **1.4** to **1.7**

Currently I'm using **Google auto-service 1.0-rc2**, so all what I had to do is putting `@AutoService(Processor.class)` annotation in my annotation processor class.

After updating **android-apt** to **1.7** version my annotation processor stopped working. It seem it is not called during build.

I thought that **auto-service** may be the issue. So I made `resources/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` file with content

```
pl.edu.radomski.navigator.NavigatorAnnotationProcessor
```

Sadly it didn't helped at all.

If you want to see the code with **android-apt 1.4** and **auto-service 1.0-rc2**  it is available [here](https://github.com/aradomski/Navigator)

Is there any simple way to upgrade android-apt and keep the processor working?

Is this **auto-service 1.0-rc2** fault or something is wrong with **android-apt**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.7 a change was made to not automatically build a dependent project that is set as `apt`, due to unwanted side effects affecting build order.

In 1.8 I'll probably have a better way to support it, but in the mean time you can configure the `apt` block to specify that your processor should be run like this:

```
apt {
 processor "pl.edu.radomski.navigator.NavigatorAnnotationProcessor"
}
```

Note that is only needed in the case your processor is in the same project as your app or library. The reason is that the file in `META-INF/services` is not read by `javac` in this setup because the project isn't packaged at that point. Explicitly adding a `processor` statement will add the processor that `javac` otherwise would not discover.